# WPF Show ToolTip without animation and transparency

Tags: wpf, tooltip, transparency

I wanna show ToolTip without any transparency (maybe to accomplish it - without animation), and hide it respectively.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the Resource :

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    >
    <Page.Resources>
        <PopupAnimation x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.ToolTipPopupAnimationKey}">None</PopupAnimation>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Button ToolTip="My ToolTip Content" Content="My Button Content" />
</Page>
```

From : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wpf/thread/a279901c-175a-4a59-a602-5ecdc66d9015

Comment: It doesn't work - there is no property setter for SystemParameters.ToolTipPopupAnimationKey